# jquery remove removes all the thing which is appending after?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my code. I am removing some elements in html with class and it removes but I am inserting some elements with class `.als-h-f` before a input field. but remove function removes these also. please suggest why this is happening?

```
if (jQuery(this).find('input[type=hidden]').length > 0) {
    jQuery('.als-h-f').remove();
    jQuery(this).find('input[type=hidden]').each(function () {
        jQuery('#search').before(jQuery(this));
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="als-cont">
    <input type="hidden" class="als-h-f" name="als_id" value="11">
    <input type="hidden" class="als-h-f" name="als_fname" value="Rajesh">
    <input type="hidden" class="als-h-f" name="als_lname" value="Sharma">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML?

Comment: edited question @rottenoats

Comment: You used `jQuery('.als-h-f').remove()` so jquery remove all `.als-h-f` that all of them is `input[type=hidden]`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Of course jQuery's `.remove()` removes all the elements you've specified. If you don't want to remove them all, you need to be more specific with your selector.

Comment: Actually i adding more hidden element after removing. it removes those also.

Comment: @AMitSiNgh You can store selected element in variable before adding new elements and after it remove selected elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't find an HTML element that you've removed from the DOM. Store them in a variable before you remove them and then add them again.

```js
$input = $('#search');
$hiddens = $('.als-h-f');
$hiddens.remove();
$hiddens.each(function(index, $hidden){
  console.log($hidden);
  $input.before($hidden);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="als-cont">
  <input type="hidden" class="als-h-f" name="als_id" value="11">
  <input type="hidden" class="als-h-f" name="als_fname" value="Rajesh">
  <input type="hidden" class="als-h-f" name="als_lname" value="Sharma">
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search">
</div>
```